# Eigenvalues of weighted Laplacian

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gershgorin-sets

Let $L_{n \times n}$ be a Laplacian matrix of a directed graph, for example, 
$$
L = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & -1\\
0 & 1  & -1\\
-1 & 0 &1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Gersgorin disc theorem tells us that all the eigenvalues of $L$ is on the closed right half plane.
If $A_i \in R^{2 \times 2}$ are positive definite matrices, can we prove that the eigenvalues of $\mathrm{diag}([A_1,A_2,\cdots,A_n])(L\otimes I_2)$, for example,
$$
L = \begin{bmatrix}
2A_1 & -A_1 & -A_1\\
0 & A_2  & -A_2\\
-A_3 & 0 & A_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
are also on the closed right half plane?
Thank you very much.